# Does Co-Op give less reward?

Tags: world-of-warships

Are rewards between the 2 modes different? I know you can't get daily missions done in Co-op, but all I really care about is XP.

It's kind of difficult to test and confirm because rewards are based on performance. So just doing matches in each mode doesn't really give a clear answer.

Does co-op (vs bots) have less base rewards than random(vs player)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you rightly said in Co-op you play against bots and in much fewer numbers then you'd encounter in a Random battle against real players.

Because of this your XP and credit rewards are heavily penalised. No one is sure of the exact percentages but current thinking is somewhere inbetween 50-75% of the XP and credits achieved per kill in the Random battles.

Aswell as the XP and credit penalty your stats from co-op battles dont count in your summary, nor do they go to completing missions which you also mentioned.

They are kind of meant as a training ground for new players or to test out that new ship you just purchased.